# jsdom and canvas gets resource as image

Tags: javascript, canvas, jsdom

I have a jsdom

```
new JSDOM(
      `<!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
              <head>
                <script src="https://www.websitewithjs.js"></script></head>
              <body>
                <p>My Test page</p>
              </body>
          </html>`,
      { runScripts: "dangerously", url: `${origin}`, origin: `${origin}`, pretendToBeVisual: true, virtualConsole: createVirtualConsole(), resources: "usable" }
    );
```

This dom loads a js that loads and adds other external js (not on my control) that executes some functions that modifies the DOM above and I'm getting an error when loading one of those resources as it gets loaded as an image

```
Could not load img: "https://externalimageserver.com/v1/get/?qp=1&qp2=value"
```

The server returns 204 with empty response and I think that could be the key of the problem.

I have canvas as a dependency but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.